# Usar método Asyntask de otra clase (Instanciar)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Deseo utilizar un método `Asyntask` que recoge un campo *preguntas* y las muestra en un `listview` este método se llama `AsyncRefrescar. Tengo otra clase donde quiero implementar dicho método y lo hago de la siguiente forma

```
VerPreguntas verPreguntas = new VerPreguntas();
verPreguntas.AsyncRefrescar().execute();
```

sin embargo esto me marca el **verPreguntas** en rojo.

El método Asyntask es el siguiente

```
public class AsyncRefrescar extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(VerPreguntas.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            url = new URL("http://bdauditorio.esy.es/Verpregunta/mostrarpre.php");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {
            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                return (result.toString());
            } else {
                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equals("unsuccessful")) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(VerPreguntas.this);
            alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
            alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no se han podido cargar las preguntas. Intentelo de nuevo.");
            alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            alertaDeError.create();
            alertaDeError.show();
        } else {
            //Existen Datos
            List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String>();

            //Parsea la respuesta obtenida por el Asynctask
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject preguntaDatos = null;
                try {
                    preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String pregunta = null;
                try {
                    pregunta = preguntaDatos.getString("pregunta");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                preguntas.add(pregunta);
            }
            //crear el Adapter.
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(VerPreguntas.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
            //Asignas el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
            mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);
            ///
        }
    }
}
```

He pensado que tal vez el dilema es el `Listview` así que he puesto el mismo **Id** en los dos `XML`

Comment: ¿Podrías  indicar de que tipo es VerPreguntas? o ¿ que es exactamente?

Comment: AsyncRefrescar esta en la clase verPreguntas???

Comment: @Joacer VerPreguntas es una clase que contiene el metodo AsyncRefrescar.

Comment: @Elenasys asi es ...

Comment: AsyncRefrescar() que devuelve? un AsyncTask?

Comment: @Joacer correcto, cabe destacar que el método es publico, public class AsyncRefrescar extends ......

Comment: @FelixBeeb felix VerPreguntas  es una Activity?   si es así simplemente llama el Asynctask de esta forma:  new AsyncRefrescar().execute();

Comment: esa forma, sirve cuando el método esta dentro de la misma clase no es asi ?

Answer (score 1):

Si es lo que pienso, no estás llamando bien el `AsyncTask`, ya que para llamar al `AsyncTask` debes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
AsyncRefrescar task = new AsyncRefrescar();
task.execute(n);
```

Aquí tienes la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Sino es esto deberás detallar un poco más el código de la clase `VerPreguntas` y el método `AsyncRefrescar()`

Comment: El método AsyncRefrescar se encuentra en otra clase llamada VerPreguntas. primero debo instanciar la clase y luego el método ?

Comment: eso sino me equivoco ya lo estas haciendo, me pregunto sino te estará dando fallo porque no le estás pasando los parámetros correctos al asynctask, ya que lo tienes declarado como AsyncTask<String, String, String> y no le estás pasando nada.

Comment: al string no le he pasado nada, de hecho en la clase donde se encuentra tampoco recibe nada y muestra el campo pregunta de la BD

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

En tu clase **VerPreguntas** crea un método publico para devolver una instancia de **AsyncRefrescar**:

```
public AsyncRefrescar getAsyncRefrescar(){
     return new AsyncRefrescar();
}
```

En la clase donde quieres usar a tu AsyncRefrescar haces lo siguiente:

```
VerPreguntas verPreguntas = new VerPreguntas();
AsyncRefrescar asynRefrescar = verPreguntas.getAsyncRefrescar();
asynRefrescar.execute();
```

Deja a tu AsyncTask con los siguientes parametros:

```
 public class AsyncRefrescar extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
```

Declara al método doInBackground

```
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
```

Comment: @Felix Beeb Actualice mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

### Como llamar un Asynctask desde otra clase.

#### La forma más simple es simplemente definiendo la clase como publica en un archivo

```
public class AsyncRefrescar extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
```

y simplemente instancia la clase:

```
AsyncRefrescar task = new AsyncRefrescar ();
task.execute();
```

#### La otra forma es creando en un archivo la clase definiendola como `abstract class`

```
abstract class AsyncRefrescar extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
```

y dentro de la clase que ejecutarías el Asynctask creas una clase que extiende de tu clase:

```
private class MyAsync extends AsyncRefrescar {

    }
```

de esta forma simplemente llama el Asynctask y se ejecutará sin problemas:

```
new MyAsync().execute();
```

#### En el caso de tu pregunta tu Asynctask, realiza modificaciones en la UI.

Por lo tanto lo mejor es agregar la clase dentro de tu Activity, ya que tienes elementos como tu listView al cual le configuras un Adapter con los resultados.

```
...
...
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(VerPreguntas.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
        //Asignas el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
        mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);
...
...
```

de esta forma si se contiene la clase del `Asynctask` en el mismo `Activity` puedes llamar sin problema de esta forma el `Asynctask`:

```
new AsyncRefrescar().execute();
```

---

Comment: no ha funcionado :c

Comment: @FelixBeeb he editado mi respuesta, considera tener tu Asynctask en una clase, o dentro del Activity

Comment: -1 Que se supone es incorrecto en lo que comento? puedo afirmar lo que comento en mi respuesta, si alguién desea platicar con gusto, saludos.

Comment: Mi Asynctask esta dentro de una clase y como nota yo no he votado en contra ...

Comment: Yo vote negativo, ya que tu explicación de como llamar a la tarea asincrona es correcta sin embargo no soluciona lo que el OP solicita*. Editaste tu pregunta y dijiste "Por lo tanto lo mejor es agregar la clase dentro de tu Activity." por la misma razon que di yo en mi respuesta.

Comment: @sioesi Esa es tu razón, sinceramente ni leí tu respuesta ni sabía habias respondido, eres de los que piensan que no se pueden editar las respuestas.

Comment: No, todo lo contrario @Elenasys, si la editaste no quiero decir que copiaste lo mio, de hecho vuelvo a reiterar que tu respuesta de como llamar a su tare asincrona esta bien (el recibe parametros, 3 String) pero no es lo que el OP necesita ya que al aplicar tu respuesta, sigue fallando porque ESTA accediendo desde otra activity a una variable que no esta inicializada (listview mostrarr) y segundo, no pertenece al UI de la activity la cual estan llamando

Answer (score 0):

En este caso no se puede, tu variable `mostrarr` es un `listview` me imagino, estas intentando acceder a elementos visuales de una `Activity` desde otra y esto no es correcto.

Si quieres obtener los mismos datos que obtiene tu tarea asíncrona puedes hacerla nuevamente en tu otra `Activity`, al ser una tarea asincrona es imposible darle un valor de retorno.

Respecto a los de id de los `listView` no influira en nada. Dentro de tu `Activity1` existe una variable llamada `mostrarr` que hace referencia al `layout` propio de dicha `Activity`. En el segundo `layout` debes crear tambien una variable que haga referencia a un objeto `ListView` y cargar la información que obtienes con tu metodo asincrono haciendo referencia a este.

Comment: El que voto negativo, por favor nos explique como acceder a un elemento visual de una activity llamandolo desde otra :)

Comment: yo no he votado negativo, pero me pregunto si podrían valer los callbacks para establecer la comunicación entre dos activities,  yo he utilizado esto alguna vez para comunicar un fragment con un Activity. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: pero un fragment es parte de una activity (una activity puede formarse de muchos fragments) por lo tanto en ese caso si puedes hacer lo que dices tu, sin embargo entre dos activitys no es posible ya que esta utilizando elementos visuales de la otra. No se puede acceder de esa manera

Comment: No voté negativo pero *si el op desea tener su Asynctask en otra clase eso no limita realizar lo que desea*, de hecho concuerdo con @Joacer se puede establecer la comunicación mediante interfaces para dentro de cada Activity realizar modificaciones, no hay que ser tan cerrado =|

Comment: Y la comunicación con interfaces (que retornaria el valor o lo guardaria, respecto al resultado de la tarea asincrona) tambien puede crear un adaptador y cargarlo en una variable de referencia a un ListView de su activity? Es ahi el problema, insisto, NO la comunicación ni tampoco donde este declarada su tarea, es ese detalle el que hace que falle

Comment: has usado interfaces? de hecho la comunicación puede ser así, porque no das opciones de código de lo que hablas en lugar de teoría, creo que el código sería más útil al usuario. Por ejemplo que mueva esos elementos del Asynctask.

Comment: nunca con 2 activitys que ocupen recursos visuales de la otra, si tu lo hazx hecho feliz de verlo y retractarme de todo lo que he hablado

Comment: No ocupan recursos visuales de otra Activity pero si que modifiquen sus propiedades mediante la comunicación entre activities. como lo comentaba joacer.

Comment: Exacto! Pero el OP menciona que en la otra Activity, intento poner el mismo id del listview por lo tanto la intencion no es modificar las propiedades entre activitis, si no cargar los mismos datos que devuelve la tarea asincrona en otra activity, no voy a estar discutiendo esto contigo de odioso o cerrado, me contextualizo en lo que el Op menciona, se que tu y Joacer tienen razon al intentar implementar esas ideas, pero no es el contexto que el OP nos deja en su pregunta! Un abrazo @Elenasys y feliz año!